# Can I get access to localStorage of site from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

My chrome extension has two state: 
 1. Some site has auth data in localStorage (another domain), so I have to show main window.
 2. There is no auth data, so I have to show window with login and password form.

In order to define if auth data is presented, I would like to check his localStorage, but it looks like it's impossible.

However, `chrome.storage.local.get` and `chrome.storage.local.set`works perfectly for localStorage of extension.

Or is there approach to do this - get access to localStorage of another site ?

Comment: Yes. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can execute a script on the page to access the local storage. There are a couple of different ways you can do this, including content scripts or injected scripts.

I'm using [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) for `async`/`await` support.

For instance in `popup.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    try {
        const key = "foobar"

        // Get the current tab
        const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
        const tab = tabs[0]; 

        // Execute script in the current tab
        const fromPageLocalStore = await chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: `localStorage['${key}']` });

        // Store the result  
        await chrome.storage.local.set({[key]:fromPageLocalStore[0]});
    } 
    catch(err) {
        // Log exceptions
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as I understand I can't get access to localStorage or coookie of closed tab ?

Comment: @EugeneShmorgun you're relying on executing code in the context of the page, you can't run code against that site outside of that context. You would be able to create a new tab and then run code inside that.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand rules: if I have authorized on my site (it means I have cookie and localStorage in page with specific domain), can I get access to this data via content_script ?

Comment: @EugeneShmorgun [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) or [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) will work, so long as you have the site open in a tab and the appropriate permissions in the manifest (either `activeTab` for just the current tab or `tabs` to access any open tab and create new ones).

Comment: @EugeneShmorgun were you able to read local storage of a domain even when no tab is open? Keith's answer makes sense of course, but only to a certain extent. Local storage in browsers were created to live outside of a tab context, but to live in a domain context, and survive closing of a tab. That's its purpose. That's why it would pretty much make sense to be able to read local storage of a domain (for which you have permissions in the Manifest) without a tab for that domain opened.

Comment: But when I try to execute this I got an error saying "chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function". any thoughts on that?

Comment: I resolved the above error by changing the code to manifest v3

Comment: @Rickfdalton this answer predates the security lock-down changes for Manifest V3 - I'm a little surprised it still works!

Comment: just need to change this line 

        const fromPageLocalStore = await chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: `localStorage['${key}']` });

to

const fromPageLocalStore = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  function: () => localStorage[key]
});

Comment: @Rickfdalton first of all, thanks a lot for updating this thread. It helps. Your key argument there however will likely be undefined since it's executed in the context of a different window (the tab's window), so you'll have to hardcode it.